# How to extract values using JSON JMESPath extractor ignoring space in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, jmespath, post-processor

I am new to JMETER, and I am facing problem while extracting values using JASON JMESPath extractor post processor, my response body is

```
[
    {
        "myid_K": "#0021",
        "myaddres": null,
        "myAddress_K": "",
    }
]
```

In my response body I am getting 100 "myid_K": "#0021", i want to extract all the 100 keys and pass it to subsequent request, I am using JASON JMESPath extractor and my $..[myid_K] and random match no is -1, I have replaced Keys in subsequent using ${myid_K_1}.

On running the query i am getting {"message":"Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context."} for the replaced request and in debug sampler it is displaying c_myid_K="myid_K", by looking at debug sampler i understood it is not collecting any values, I checked with JSMEPATH extractor generator which is available in JSMEPath.org and in that it is showing null in result, so my question is there way where i can ignore space (myid_K": "#0021) between : and " and extract keys.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an invalid [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) query, you should use something like:

```
[0].myid_K
```

[image]

The query you're using:

1. Looks like [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
2. Uses "deep scan" operator which doesn't have an equivalent in JMESPath

So it might be the case you should use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) instead